# How do you prevent an entire PDF file to be downloaded in PDF.js?

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

If you go to [this](https://jsfiddle.net/pdfjs/wagvs9Lf/) page you will see an example of how [PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/) works.  When clicking on "Run" button, you will see it successfully downloads the entire 14 pages of the PDF file and initially displays the first page.  When you click on the "Next" button it will show you the next page of the PDF file (if one exists).

My question: How do you prevent PDF.js from downloading all 14 pages and only download the first 3 pages? Note that you can show only the first 3 pages by making the following change in JS Fiddle below:

Change:

```
function onNextPage() {
  if (pageNum >= pdfDoc.numPages) {
    return;
  }
  pageNum++;
  queueRenderPage(pageNum);
}
```

to

```
/**
 * Displays next page.
 */
function onNextPage() {
  if (pageNum >= 3) { // <--- don't show beyond 3rd page
    return;
  }
  pageNum++;
  queueRenderPage(pageNum);
}
```

But the problem with this is if you go to the javascript console and enter:

```
renderPage(14)
```

PDF.js will show you the 14th page.  This means the entire PDF file has been downloaded, however I only want the first 3 pages to be downloaded.  We are working with PDF files that can be 500 or 1000 pages, so limiting the amount to download is key here.

Would appreciate all / any advise on how this can be done in PDF.js.

Comment: I have the exact same question. It might be possible to use AJAX to download the first page, and then convert it to base64, and then embed it to the website, but not sure.